# Drawer is overlapping Navbar in react material ui app, do you know how to change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, navigation-drawer, z-index

I want to let the drawer disappear behind my navbar when it is opened. Currently, the drawer is overlaying the navbar. I tried to change it with z-index in my "styles" but apparently it does not work (see screenshot). I set the z-index for the navbar higher than for the drawer.

Can you identify my mistake?

Here is the drawer.js:

```
import React from "react";
import clsx from "clsx";
import { makeStyles, useTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Drawer from "@material-ui/core/Drawer";

const drawerWidth = 240;

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    display: "flex",
  },
  drawer: {
    width: drawerWidth,
    zIndex: 400,
    flexShrink: 0,
    /*whiteSpace: "nowrap",*/
  },
  drawerOpen: {
    width: drawerWidth,
    transition: theme.transitions.create("width", {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
    }),
  },
```

And here is my navbar.js:

```
// import packages
import React, { useContext, Fragment } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

// import local dependenceis
import Logo from "./images/tubot_logo.png";
import AuthContext from "../../Context/Auth/authContext";

// import material-ui
import withStyles from "@material-ui/core/styles/withStyles";
import AppBar from "@material-ui/core/AppBar";
import Toolbar from "@material-ui/core/Toolbar";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";


// styling
const styles = (theme) => {
  return {
    root: {
      flexGrow: 1,
      zIndex: 2000,
    },
    title: {
      flexGrow: 1,
      fontFamily: "shadowsintolight",
      textDecoration: "none",
      color: "black",
    },
   
};

const Navbar = (props) => {
  // destructuring: styling props
  const {
    root,
    title,
 

  } = props.classes;

 

  // react: return jsx
  return (
    <div className={root}>
      <AppBar position="absolute" >
        <Toolbar>
          /*some navbar stuff*/
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `classes` prop on your `Drawer` component like this:

```
const App = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <div className="App" className={root}>
      <AppBar position="absolute">
        <Toolbar>
          // Toolbar content...
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      <Drawer
        variant="persistent"
        anchor="left"
        open={true}
        classes={{
          paper: classes.drawer,
        }}>
        // Drawer content...
      </Drawer>
    </div>
  );
};
```